# Json Deserializing to null using Newtosoft Json

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I have the following json:

```
{
  "cuisines": [
    {
      "cuisine": {
        "cuisine_id": 152,
        "cuisine_name": "African"
      }
    },
    {
      "cuisine": {
        "cuisine_id": 1,
        "cuisine_name": "American"
      }
    },
    {
      "cuisine": {
        "cuisine_id": 4,
        "cuisine_name": "Arabian"
      }
    },
    {
      "cuisine": {
        "cuisine_id": 151,
        "cuisine_name": "Argentine"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

Im using RestSharp to get the data and sending it to JSON.Net:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cuisines>(content)
```

And I'm using the following classes:

```
public class Cuisine
    {
        [JsonProperty("cuisine_id")]
        public string cuisine_id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cuisine_name")]
        public string cuisine_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cuisines
    {
        [JsonProperty("cuisines")]
        public List<Cuisine> AllCuisines { get; set; } 
    }
```

What is wierd is, the return data is finding 81 cuisine objects on my request, but all the Cuisine info is null.

Comment: See [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com)

Comment: @MalteR Visual Studio will do that for you

Comment: @Plutonix Don't you need the Web Essentials plugin for that?

Comment: @MalteR I used it, but props to pointing it out. I had to post the entire json there, instead of the documentation on the API page.

Comment: **Paste Special** -> **Paste JSON as Classes**.  I think as of VS2010 @MalteR

Comment: @Plutonix Cool, will use that instead next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You model needs one more class. So it should be

```
public class Cuisine
{
    [JsonProperty("cuisine_id")]
    public string cuisine_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cuisine_name")]
    public string cuisine_name { get; set; }
}

public class CuisineWrapper
{
    public Cuisine cuisine { get; set; }
}

public class Cuisines
{
    [JsonProperty("cuisines")]
    public List<CuisineWrapper> AllCuisines { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your classes definitions doesn't match provided JSON. Top level array contains objects with a single property (object) `cuisine`, like so:

```
"cuisine": {
    "cuisine_id": 152,
    "cuisine_name": "African"
}
```

where as your C# `List<Cuisine>` contains objects directly exposing `cuisine_id` and `cuisine_name`. If you can't change JSON, decorate `class Cuisine` with [JsonObjectAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonObjectAttribute.htm)

Comment: You should add an example of how to use `[JsonObject]`, it sounds like a better solution than adding a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have 3 objects - A root object that contains a property named `cuisines` that is a collection of `Cuisine`.
When you paste your JSON as classes in visual studio you get the following structure (which you would probably want to rename some things and list-ify the array)

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Cuisine[] cuisines { get; set; }
}

public class Cuisine
{
    public Cuisine1 cuisine { get; set; }
}

public class Cuisine1
{
    public int cuisine_id { get; set; }
    public string cuisine_name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON is nested more than your class structure. If you can change your JSON to the form:

```
"cuisines": [
    {
        "cuisine_id": 152,
        "cuisine_name": "African"
    },
    {
        "cuisine_id": 1,
        "cuisine_name": "American"
    },
    .. etc
```

Then it will match your class structure.

Alternatively, change your class structure to match the JSON:

```
public class Cuisine
{
    [JsonProperty("cuisine")]
    public CuisineData data { get; set; }
}

public class CuisineData
{
    [JsonProperty("cuisine_id")]
    public string cuisine_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cuisine_name")]
    public string cuisine_name { get; set; }
}

public class Cuisines
{
    [JsonProperty("cuisines")]
    public List<Cuisine> AllCuisines { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I cant change the json. Its a response from an API

Comment: See my edit. Also, you didn't mention whether you controlled the web-api or not - so it was a reasonable assumption that you might.